# How to access gitlab server on external ip

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I installed gitlab server on a local server.
my local ip:

```
http://192.168.8.52/
```

Now I can access gui gitlab server from external network with this ip:
http://**.**.**.122:2022/users/sign_in

but when I want to clone from this Ip :

```
$ git clone git@**.**.**.122:2022:algorithmbartar/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
ssh: connect to host **.**.**.122 port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: Ignoring git for a minute, can you SSH into your server from your machine?

Comment: `port 22: Connection timed out` sounds like a firewall is blocking traffic on port 22.

Comment: Can you try cloning with an HTTP URL?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a different URL format for the custom port:

`git clone ssh://git@IP:2022/algorithmbar/test.git`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to clone with git on the same port 2022 you are using to expose the web interface on the internet.

If you use the http(s) port you need to clone with https:
git clone https://gitlabuser:password@gitlab.myconpany.tld/mygroup/myproject.git

if you clone with git you need to expose the port 22 of your internal server on the external IP with another port (7022? 10022?)

I think you better expose the web interface on a xx80 port, it is clear and easier to remeber.